# Как добавить вторую переменную

Tags: php, mysql, sql

С массивом  $array все работает верно, добавляется определенное количество строк и заносится в каждую строку ячейка со значением  $array = $_POST[form_text_o]; , но вот как мне сделать чтобы добавлялось две ячейки где в первой значение $array, а вторая ячейка со значением $arrayy

```
$array = $_POST[form_text_o];
```

`$arrayy = $_POST[form_text_opis];`

```
$query = "INSERT INTO opisanie (text,text_opis) VALUES ('" . implode("'), ('", $array ) . "')";

$res = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: не понял вашего вопроса

Comment: ну вот смотрите, этот запрос создает в БД строку с одной ячейкой равана переменной $array, но вот как мне сделать чтобы в БД создавалась строка с заполнением двух ячеей, где вторая ячейка будет равана переменной $arrayy

Comment: А что это `('" . implode("'), ('", $array )` за интересная конструкция и для чего? ........ и почему тут `(text,text_opis)` два столбца, а вставить, видимо, пытаетесь три....хотя я вообще не понимаю чего вы там пытаетесь вставить

Comment: `$_POST[form_text_o]` и `$_POST[form_text_opis]` являются массивами?

Comment: @Gedweb да, это массивы

Comment: @harbor, обновил ответ. Хочу предупредить, такой способ передачи данных может легко "поехать", гарантировать очередность элементов массивов проблематично

Comment: @Gedweb спасибо, сейчас попробую и дам ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен некий конструктор запроса, который добавит несколько значений за раз:

```
function createQuery($a, $b){
    $query = "INSERT INTO opisanie (text,text_opis) VALUES ";
    $limit = count($a);
    for($i=0; $i<$limit; $i++){
        $query .= "('{$a[$i]}', '{$b[$i]}')".($i!=$limit-1?',':'');
    }
    return $query;
}

$aText = array('один','два','три');
$aOpis = array('один_один','два_два','три_три');

$query = createQuery($aText, $aOpis);
$res = mysql_query($query);
```

Нужно понимать что нужно еще проверить кол-во значений в массиве, необходимо одинаковое кол-во, иначе будут ошибки, обработать данное поведение. Проверить заранее что там вам приходит в пост массивах, безопасность как никак. Забыть об использовании `mysql` (если вам конечно не надо работать в старых версиях), и пользоваться `mysqli` или `pdo`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, сейчас проверю

Comment: не работает, может что-то не так сделал 
function addRow($array){
    $query = "INSERT INTO opisanie (text,text_opis) VALUES ('" . implode("'), ('", $array ) . "')";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
}

addRow ($_POST[form_text_o]);
addRow ($_POST[form_text_opis]);

Comment: а что должно работать? и как вообще вы пришли к такому решению?

Comment: @harbor вы пробовали без постов ?

Comment: нет, дело в  том что там значения будут браться из $_POST, по-другому никак, мне нужен второй столбец, так как вторая строка у меня уже делается из массива

Comment: @harbor вам вторая строка нужна или второй столбец?

Comment: нужен второй столбец

Comment: @harbor изменил ответ

Comment: @Bookin вы гений, запрос строится правильно `INSERT INTO opisanie (text,text_opis) VALUES ('один', 'один_один'),('два', 'два_два'),('три', 'три_три')`,  но вот в БД не грузит, но запрос вроде верный

Comment: посмотрите `mysql_error()`

Comment: @Bookin спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: @Bookin ошибка была в том что переменную `$res = mysql_query($query);` нужно было поместить в функцию, а вы вынесли ее за скобки

Comment: @harbor Прощу прощения за [свою проверку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/134379) вашей правки: не читая комментарии нажал отклонить. Торопился, показалась вандальной, нарушающей мысль автора. Надеюсь, остальные проверяющие будут более бдительными и на общем итоге не скажется.

Comment: @AK спасибо за комментарий, увидел ошибку)

Comment: Мммм, надо было принять-и-править, а не отклонить-и-править. Вы новичку попортили статистику: у @harbor 0 принятых правок и теперь вот первая же отклонённая.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас очень старый код, либо учебник.

Функции `mysql_*` не просто устаревшие, а удалённые из последних версий php.

Мой пример использует [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)

```
$input = [
    ['hello', 'some', 'text'],
    ['world', 'message', 'description'],
];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testme', 'user', 'password');

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT example(col1, col2) value(?, ?)');
for ($i = 0; $i < count($input[0]); ++$i) {
    $row = array_column($input, $i);
    $stmt->execute($row);
}
```

В Вашем случае:

```
$input = [
    $_POST['form_text_o'],
    $_POST['form_text_opis'],
];
```

Использование конкатенации в SQL-запросе приводит к уязвимости. Учитесь писать правильно с самого начала - используйте подготовленные запросы.

Comment: Кажется автор имел в виду совсем не то, что мы тут нарешали :D

Comment: Такое случается. Меня больше напрягло `mysql`

Comment: и всё же value**S** ;-)

Comment: я изменил суть вопроса, посмотрите пожалуйста и скажите понятна проблема или нет

Comment: Советую ознакомиться с документацией
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Comment: @Gedweb и часто вы это видите в запросах? Общепринято всё равно писать с "S" хоть тысячу запросов пересмотрите, никто так не пишет, ибо устоялось иная форма записи.... тем более нелогично вставлять значени**Я**, а писать valu**E**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вопрос синтаксических возможностей в данном топике не обсуждается.  Можете писать свои ответы, как "общепринято", Вам ни кто не мешает. Воздержитесь от последующего редактирования ответов пользователей в соответствие со своими убеждениями

Comment: @Gedweb это **НЕ мои личные** предпочтения и убеждения, а вполне устоявшиеся негласные нормы....А править мне никто не мешает :D

Comment: @Gedweb спасибо большое вы очень сильно помогли, все работает отлично, вам нет цены!!

Comment: @harbor, рад помочь

Comment: @Gedweb появилась ошибка, при добавлении одной строки выдает ошибку `PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound`, а при добавлении трех строк добавляются только первые две строки

Comment: @harbor, обратите внимание - код был обновлен после принятия ответа.

Comment: Даешь PDO в массы!

Answer (score 0):

```
function addRow($array){
    $query = "INSERT INTO `opisanie` (`text`,`text_opis`) VALUES ('" . implode("','", $array) . "')";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
}

addRow(array('один','два','три'));
addRow(array('один_один','два_два','три_три'));
```

Так должно работать

Answer (score 0):

```
 function addRow($arr1, $arr2){
for ($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++){
    $query=sprintf("INSERT INTO opisanie (text,text_opis) VALUES('%s','%s')", $arr1[$i], $arr2[$i] );
    $res = mysql_query($query);
}
}

addRow($array, $arrayy);
```

Это если количество элементов в обоих массивах одинаковое.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я добавил ваш код, но дело в том что мне выдает ошибку  syntax error, unexpected end of file in, меня смущает вот эта часть в коде $query=sprintf(..., можно ли оставить как прежде было в моем варианте $query = "...

Comment: я одну скобку не закрыл. добавьте } перед addRow($array, $arrayy);

Comment: Ваш вариант sql запроса не работает, потому, что Вы не понимаете, что делаете. Если Вы хотите добавить много значений сразу, то запрос должен выглядеть по другому. В данном случае вам надо на каждой итерации отправлять по одному значению из каждого массива. а для этого нужен цикл.

Comment: sprintf очень простая функция, посмотрите:
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Исправил ответ. добавил скобку.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже вы пытаетесь сделать что-то типа такого:

```
$array = array('один','два','три');
$arrayy = array('один_один','два_два','три_три');

$query = 'INSERT INTO opisanie (text,text_opis) 
          VALUES ("'.implode('", "', $array ).'"),
                 ("'.implode('", "', $arrayy ).'")';

$res = mysql_query($query);
```

У вас все равно остается масса косяков для исправления:

- использование `mysql` расширения
- вставляются 3 значения, хотя пишите `opisanie (text,text_opis)`, т.е. ожидаете только два.
- если таких массивов будет много, то вставлять надо будет через цикл
- ну и конечно нужно всё это делать в соответствии с подготовленными переменными в нормальном адекватном расширении `mysqli` или `PDO`, которым надо будет заменить `mysql`

P.S. Ну и напомню, что в *MySQL* можно добавлять несколько `VALUES` за раз:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

как пример

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Comment: Ответы с косяками лучше не писать

Comment: @Gedweb это не мои косяки, а автора.

Comment: представьте, что это Ваш будущий коллега. Стали бы так писать в своём проекте?

Comment: @Gedweb читай ответ, прежде чем комментировать

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, но я только что попробовал ваш вариант, но он не работает

Comment: @harbor он работает, если вы обратите на пункт, который я озвучил в ответе и в комментарии под вопросом.............повторю третий раз: вы пытаетесь вставлять 3 значения, хотя пишите `opisanie (text,text_opis)`, т.е. ожидаете только два....... либо вставляйте 2 значения, либо объявляйте для вставки три столбца

Comment: $array и $arrayy это два значения, а все что находится в них это количество строк

Comment: @harbor нет, это два массива, а значений в них **по три** и `implode` в результате преобразует массив из **трех** значений в строку с **тремя** значениями

Comment: `VALUES ("'.implode('", "', $array ).'"),
                 ("'.implode('", "', $arrayy ).'")'; ` зачем вы прописали добавление двух строк если количество строк определяется из массива

Comment: это у вас не массив, в моем случае там массив

Comment: @harbor вот на столько вы невнятно написали вопрос, что все поняли вас абсолютно также, как я, а не как вы себе в голове напридумывали :D  Советую явно чётко написать свой вопрос, нажав на "править"

Comment: исправил вопрос, думаю он будет более понятен, прочтите пожалуйста и сообщите как вы смотрите на это